# test coverage report not being generated properly with subprocess module

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pytest, code-coverage

I'm using pycov to generate the coverage report for a python tool  that I've developed.

**Workflow ♻:-** *Test Script -> Calls function from Helper File (Uses **Subprocess** to interact with **Tool.py**) -> Gets the **stdout** back and returns it to the test script.*

⭐*Coverage report needs to be generated for **Tool.py***

---

***Even the the codeblocks are hit during the testing phase, they are being shown as not being covered in the coverage report generated in pycov.***

---

This script runs all the test scripts.

```
for i in file_list:
    if i.startswith("test_"):
        test_files.append(i)
for file in test_files:
    result_file_name = file.split(".")[0] + ".xml"
    pytest.main([file, "-o", "junit_logging=system-out","--disable-pytest-warnings",
              "--junitxml=" + result_folder + result_file_name, "--tb=line",
              "--cov", "--cov-config=.coveragerc", "--cov-report=html", "--cov-report=", "--cov-append"])
```

In the .coveragerc file

```
[run]
branch = True
dynamic_context = test_function
include = Tool.py
```

Does anybody know a solution for this? Please do let me know, thanks!